# How to Remove the class 'in' dynamically which is inbuilt class in bootstrap when only clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

when clicked on the button the class "in" in div element must be removed dynamically.

```
`<div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code.

**Explanation**

In this example, `in` class render element as **bold**.

A very simple directive called `onclick-toggle-class` declared as an attribute of the element binds `onclick` event on this element and add/remove the css class passed in param (We use the directive attribute value).

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('toggleNextElementClass', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind('click', function() {
          // get next element
          var nextElement = element[0].nextElementSibling;
          if(nextElement) {
          angular.element(nextElement).toggleClass(attrs.toggleNextElementClass);
          }
          });
      }
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
.collapse { display: none; }
.in { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" toggle-next-element-class="in">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div class="collapse in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the above solution din't work..it should actually work like when clicked on the button the class in the <div> element ie:- "in" must be removed so that it remains closed and active state gets removed..

Comment: In fact, it worked if `in` class was not present at first time. I refactored my example using a simple directive with some explanation ;)

Comment: yes.but what i need is..at first initially "in" class will be used.so that its in active state initially.but need to get rid of it when we click..so that it remains closed until we click again.so is there a solution..??

Comment: `in` class is initialy available in the element classes list, and when you click it removes it. If it's not what was expected, then be more clearer in your explanation because I don't understand what's wrong with my updated answer. Sorry.